# Is there some data limit preventing all of this data from being sent? Any help would be appreciated! :)

Tags: python, java, sockets, stock

I'm building a program to compile and compress yfinance data for a group of stocks and put the data in a .txt file. This requires me to run a python program that sends the data to a java program over  a socket. When I run the python server and then the java client though, the program only sends some of the data, and suddenly stops after a chunk of the data is sent causing the program to hang.

Here is the python server

```
import socket
import yfinance as yf
import pandas as pd
import datetime as dt


pd.options.display.max_rows = 2000000

with socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) as s:
    s.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
    s.bind(("127.0.0.1", 65432))
    s.listen()
    conn, addr = s.accept()
    with conn:
        print(f"Connected by {addr}")
        while True:
            data = conn.recv(1024)
            if not data:
                print('nodata')
                break
            stringdata = data.decode('utf-8')
            print(stringdata)
            if stringdata == "end":
                break
            start1 = stringdata[0:10]
            start = dt.datetime(int(start1[0:4]), int(start1[5:7]), int(start1[8:10]))
            end1 = stringdata[10:20]
            end = dt.datetime(int(end1[0:4]), int(end1[5:7]), int(end1[8:10]))
            tticker = yf.Ticker(stringdata[20:])
            print(tticker.history(start=start, end=end, interval="5m")
            stringdata2 = str(data2)
            print(stringdata2)
            conn.sendall(bytes(stringdata2, 'utf-8'))
        s.close()
```

And here is the Java client

```
import java.net.*;
import java.text.NumberFormat;
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.time.LocalDate;
//import org.javatuples.*;
import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.time.LocalTime;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;  
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class main{

    public static ArrayList<String> Tickers = new ArrayList<String>();
    public static File stockTracker = new File("StockTracking.txt");
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, ParseException, InterruptedException{
        
//      ArrayList<String> NYSETickers = new ArrayList<String>();
//      ArrayList<String> NASDAQTickers = new ArrayList<String>();
        int x = 65;
        char y;
        String z;
        String x1;
        while(x <= 90) {
            y = (char)x;
            z = String.valueOf(y);
            x1 = "https://eoddata.com/stocklist/NYSE/" + z + ".htm";
            URL tickers = new URL(x1);
            URLConnection tCon = tickers.openConnection();
            InputStreamReader tStream = new InputStreamReader(tCon.getInputStream());
            BufferedReader tBuff = new BufferedReader(tStream);

            String oline = tBuff.readLine();
            while(oline != null) {
                if(oline.contains("NYSE,")){
                    String gx = oline.substring(oline.indexOf("/NYSE/") + 6, oline.indexOf(".htm"));
                    if(!(gx.equals("BRK.A")) && !(gx.equals("EVN"))) {
                    //System.out.println(gx);
                    //System.out.println(Integer.parseInt(oline.substring(oline.indexOf("<td align=right>") + 16, oline.indexOf("<td align=right>") + 17)));
                    System.out.println(oline.substring(oline.indexOf("<td align=right>") + 17, oline.indexOf("<td align=right>") + 18));
                    System.out.println(oline.substring(oline.indexOf("<td align=right>") + 94, oline.indexOf("</td><td align=\"right\">")));
                    try {
                    if(!(Integer.parseInt(oline.substring(oline.indexOf("<td align=right>") + 16, oline.indexOf("<td align=right>") + 17)) < 5 && oline.substring(oline.indexOf("<td align=right>") + 17, oline.indexOf("<td align=right>") + 18).equals(".")) && NumberFormat.getNumberInstance(java.util.Locale.US).parse(oline.substring(oline.indexOf("<td align=right>") + 94, oline.indexOf("</td><td align=\"right\">"))).intValue() > 1000000) {
                        Tickers.add(gx);
                        System.out.println(gx);
                    }
                    }catch(ParseException e) {
                        Tickers.add(gx);
                    }
                    }
                }
                oline = tBuff.readLine();
            }
            y = (char)x;
            z = String.valueOf(y);
            x1 = "https://eoddata.com/stocklist/NASDAQ/" + z + ".htm";
            URL ntickers = new URL(x1);
            URLConnection nCon = ntickers.openConnection();
            InputStreamReader nStream = new InputStreamReader(nCon.getInputStream());
            BufferedReader nBuff = new BufferedReader(nStream);

            String nline = nBuff.readLine();
            while(nline != null) {
                if(nline.contains("NASDAQ,")){
                    String gx = nline.substring(nline.indexOf("/NASDAQ/") + 8, nline.indexOf(".htm"));
                    //if(!(gx.equals("BRK.A")) && !(gx.equals("EVN"))) {
                    //System.out.println(gx);
                    //System.out.println(Integer.parseInt(oline.substring(oline.indexOf("<td align=right>") + 16, oline.indexOf("<td align=right>") + 17)));
                    //System.out.println(nline.substring(nline.indexOf("<td align=right>") + 17, nline.indexOf("<td align=right>") + 18));
                    //System.out.println(oline.substring(oline.indexOf("<td align=right>") + 94, oline.indexOf("</td><td align=\"right\">")));
                    try {
                    if(!(Integer.parseInt(nline.substring(nline.indexOf("<td align=right>") + 16, nline.indexOf("<td align=right>") + 17)) < 5 && nline.substring(nline.indexOf("<td align=right>") + 17, nline.indexOf("<td align=right>") + 18).equals(".")) && NumberFormat.getNumberInstance(java.util.Locale.US).parse(nline.substring(nline.indexOf("<td align=right>") + 94, nline.indexOf("</td><td align=\"right\">"))).intValue() > 1000000) {
                        Tickers.add(gx);
                        System.out.println(gx);
                    }
                    }catch(ParseException e) {
                        Tickers.add(gx);
                    }
                    }
                //}
                nline = nBuff.readLine();
            }
            x++;
        }
        for(String tick:Tickers) {
            System.out.println(tick);
        }
        
            
        
        
        
            Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);
            
            Socket transmission = new Socket("localhost", 65432);
            System.out.println("Socket Created");
            
            Reader reader = new InputStreamReader(transmission.getInputStream());
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(reader);
            
            //InputStream in3 = transmission.getInputStream();
            
            Writer writer = new OutputStreamWriter(transmission.getOutputStream());
            BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(writer);
            
            FileWriter dWriter = new FileWriter("StockTracking.txt");
            initData(in, out);
            out.write("end");
            transmission.close();
            System.out.println("Socket Closed");
public static boolean initData(BufferedReader in, BufferedWriter out) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        LocalDate edate = LocalDate.now().minusDays(1);
        LocalDate sdate = LocalDate.now().minusDays(40);
        String ssdate = sdate.format(DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_DATE);
        String sedate = edate.format(DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_DATE);
        
        PrintWriter pw =  new PrintWriter(new FileWriter(stockTracker));
        for(String ticker:Tickers) {
        System.out.println(ticker);
         out.write(ssdate + sedate + ticker);
         out.flush();
         Thread.sleep(10);
         //System.out.println("Kill" + in.readLine());
         //System.out.println("Kill" + in.readLine());
         pw.println(ticker);
         String x;
         while(true) {
             //System.out.println(i);
             x = in.readLine();
             System.out.println(x);
             if(x.length() > 25 && x.substring(0, 1).equals("2")) {
                 pw.println(x.substring(5, 7) + x.substring(8, 10) + x.substring(11, 13) + x.substring(14, 16) + x.substring(27, x.indexOf(".") + 2));
                 if(x.substring(5, 7).equals("07")) {
                 if(x.substring(8, 10).equals("21")) {
                     if(x.substring(11, 13).equals("15")) {
                         if(x.substring(14, 16).equals("55")) {
                             break;
                         }
                     }  
                 }
                 }
             }
         }
         //System.out.println("Kill" + in.readLine());
         pw.flush();
        }
        pw.close();
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: You should reduce your code to a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). This will help others help you.

Comment: In particular, are the requests to remote services really needed to trigger the problem, or can it be reproduced with just the Python and Java programs communicating using hardcoded data?